# Vue js multiselect hide triangle with empty

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) library. How can I hide this triangle if the data is empty?

[image: Screenshot]

```vue
<multiselect v-model="user.majors" id="majorsSearch" label="name" track-by="id" placeholder="Search majors..." select-label="Select" :options="majorsBag" :multiple="true" :loading="isLoadingMajors" :internal-search="false" :clear-on-select="true" :close-on-select="true" @search-change="asyncFindMajors">
    <template slot="tag" scope="props"></template>
</multiselect>
```

Comment: could you add an event that will be fired when you click on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the default dropdown button by providing the `caret` slot; in your situation you can use an empty `<span>`, try something like this:

```vue
<multiselect v-model="user.majors">
  <span slot="caret" v-if="!user.majors.length"></span>
</multiselect>
```